# Trying to periodically backup /var/log while using journald

Tags: cron, backup, systemd-journald

I'm trying to periodically backup my `/var/log` directory, but journald manages the logging on my system. Is the correct way to just `tar -cf log.tar /var/log`?

The way journald saves it's log files in `/var/log/journal/xxx/system.journal` makes me think that the above mentioned way is wrong, does journald have some backup options built in?

Answer (score 0):

You would better use logrotate to "archive" in gz format logs files (trigger actions when needed...as some software don't like to see their log file vanished)

For the second behaviour expected the command to dump systemctl journal is (for example with sshd unit) : `journalctl -u sshd -S today --no-tail > main.log`

source :
https://serverfault.com/questions/728231/getting-journald-logs-to-a-plain-text-file